# Random Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, random-effects-model

I am a student. I have some knowledge of mixed regression models. I would like to implement Random Regression in R.
I found "Random Regression Models" by Schaeffer (http://animalbiosciences.uoguelph.ca/~lrs/BOOKS/rrmbook.pdf) helpful.
I have also read "MCMCglmm Course Notes" by Jarrod Hadfield (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) Chapter 4 discusses random regression.

My questions: Is "Random Regression" know by a different name, can anybody suggest a good fundamental learning resource that covers this? Preferable a text-book or tutorial type resource.

Thanks Greg

Comment: The common name is mixed model. If you search mixed model, maybe you can get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from another source:
Randon Regression is short for Random "effects" regression, also known as multilevel models or hierarchical models. Depending on your data structure it can also be referred to as repeated measures analysis. It all depends on the field.
This confirms @user158565's answer.
Thank-you.